# Django-credit-card error invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'cc_expiry'

Tags: django

Please I need some assistance on django-credit-card. This is the official doc i was referencing. https://pypi.org/project/django-credit-cards/

This is the error i'm getting, invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'cc_expiry'

this is my model

```
class CreditCard(models.Model):
cc_number = CardNumberField(_('card number'))
cc_expiry = CardExpiryField(_('expiration date'))
cc_code = SecurityCodeField(_('security code'))
```

this is my modelform

```
class CreditCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = CreditCard
    fields = ['cc_number', 'cc_expiry', 'cc_code']
```

views

```
class CreatCardView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
template_name = 'transactions/create-card.html'
form_class = CreditCardForm
success_url = '/transactions/view-card/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        
        form.save()
    print(form.cleaned_data)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: What value are you trying to assign to cc_expiry?

Comment: expiration date e.g 03/23

Answer (score 0):

Following `CardExpiryField` you can see that this field inherits from DateField, so you should pass Date to it instead of string

Comment: like 0324? where 03 is the month and 24 is the year?

Comment: Like converting string to Datetime using strptime and then passing date from it to CardExpiryField